# iPhone - trying to understand UIBezier in CGContext

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

When I have a UIBezier and I stoke it on a view using drawRect I see the bezier is a a kind of volatile, I mean, it is really not drawn anywhere. Instead it is like it was written in a kind of buffer that corresponds to what I see on that view. I mean, if I invoke drawRect again using [self setNeedsDisplay] the bezier is gone and I can write other stuff.

On the other hand, if I draw a like on a CGContext using

```
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

I am really writing the line to that context and there's no way to erase it and if I call the same method again, it will write over the context that now has already one line drawn.

But what happens when I use a UIBezier command to write on a CGContext?

I mean, if I do something like

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
[myBezier stroke];
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

is this line permanently written to ctx or is it volatile as before? The docs contain no information about it and are vague as always.

thanks

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question, although it took me a couple of reads to get it.

Comment: it has certainly something to do with the fact that english is not my natural language... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your view's `drawRect:` gets called, UIKit has set up a graphics context for you to draw into. That's why it appears that the bezier paths aren't permanent; every time the view needs to be displayed there's a fresh new context, and your paths get drawn into that. Each time through `drawRect:`, therefore, you can decide not to draw a particular path and it won't be displayed.

There's no way to remove a path once it's been added to the context, but the next time the view is refreshed, there's a new context with almost nothing in it. If you create your own graphics context, whatever you put into it is "permanent" -- it will be there for the lifetime of the context.

The context basically consists of drawing instructions that will produce a "picture". This is vague because the destination for a context -- where the picture will be drawn -- can be different things: an image file, a section of the device screen, possibly even a piece of paper. The context, once it's full of drawing instructions, then gets rendered to its destination.

In the case of your view drawing, UIKit sets up that context for you and calls your `drawRect:`. There's a certain amount of indirection here -- you're never really "drawing into a view", *always* into a context. Your view essentially reserves and represents a section of the screen. UIKit asks you what you would like to put into that section, and gives you the graphics context so that you can convey that information. Then it takes the context, which is full of instructions, turns it into pixel data, and paints that in the area represented by your view.

Comment: but in my code, when I stroke, where am I drawing? on ctx or in the view?

Answer (score 1):

`UIBezierPath` is a class that encompasses a series of lines/curves and instructions on how to draw them. When you draw a bezier path, it essentially does the same thing as any other drawing function in Quartz. The content of the context will persist for the lifetime of the context (for a bitmap context, that's the lifetime of the bitmap in memory; for a view context, that's "until the view needs to be redrawn.")

Comment: if this is true, why does the appearance of the line changes if I change its property and write it again. For example: I draw a dashed blue line. THen, I write a solid red line. Suddenly, when I do that, all lines are now solid and if I write a dashed line over the others, all other turn dashed. See this other question of mine...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318972/iphone-stroking-an-array-of-uibezierpaths-with-different-attributes-on-a-cgcont

Comment: The code in that question is rather bizarre. I suggest you read more about [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) at Apple's website.